# Can I set rowTemplate to other colors in ng-grid？

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I am trying to give users ability to choose the color they want to highlight the cells they want in `ng-grid`, but it seems `ng-grid` *can only set cells to green not other color*.

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Where did you get the impression cells could only be green? They're green in the example on [this doc](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/), but the code given shows why: the cell template uses `ng-class` to choose a class based on the data given. You could do the same thing with any CSS class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Austin! The thing I am wondering is that I cannot change the cell color by just simply change _green_ to something else in the ng-class property `<div ng-class="{green: row.getProperty(col.field) > 30}">`

Comment: You'll need to put more code into your question. I'm not sure I follow. If you created a CSS class with a different background color, you should be able to use it in `ng-class`.